# Test with mocha and chai to see if a promise is resolved or rejected

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, mocha.js, chai

I wrote a function that takes some arguments and inside the function it uses a class that has a function from a 3rd party library that returns a promise and I return this result of the promise in my own function. like :

```
return client.track(data) // client.track is from a 3rd party lib that should return a promise
```

Now I want to test the return of the promise in my mocha + chai testing file. I import this function with the inputs and I should get the result. something like:

```
const result = await myfunc(x,y) // Should return the result of a promise
```

now I want to test if the promise was actually resolved or rejected in mocha + chai, like using

```
chai.expect(...)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the npm package `chai-as-promised`(https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised). It's an extension to the chai library which offers support for promises.

You can set it up in the following way

```
const chai            = require("chai")
const chaiAsPromised  = require("chai-as-promised")

chai.use(chaiAsPromised)
chai.should()

promiseFunction(args).should.be.rejectedWith(SomeError)
promiseFunction().should.eventually.be.a('array')
```

Take a look at the documentation to get a better idea of the power of this plugin :)

Comment: Interesting, will look into it. As I am doing this for a big project that wants as mess dependencies as possible, do you know if this can be done with regular chai? Even if it can be way messier, i will prefer it for a one time promise test

Comment: I had the same problem originally and I could never get vanilla Chai to work well with promises. If it does make you feel any better, the `chai-as-promised` package is  officially recognised by the team behind Chai (https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/)

Answer (score 0):

This works, but requires a little bit of boilerplate.

```
await expect(await myPromise.then(() => true)).to.be.true
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I am using with `mocha` to test rejected promises.  It is ugly and verbose, but avoids adding more test dependencies, and avoids false positives.

```
describe('when an awaited promise is rejected', () => {
  it('should raise an error', async () => {
    try {
      await someAsyncFunctionThatWillReject()
      assert(false) // will fail the test if no error
    } catch(e) {
      assert(true)  // passes only if there was an error
    }
  })
})
```

The final `assert(true)` does not really affect test results, but it makes the test more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a specific assertion inside the catch section, something like:

```
chai.expect(e).to.be.an.instanceOf(Error);
chai.expect(e.message).to.be.not.null;
```

The expect method comes from the **chai** library which usually partners with mocha.